# Cordova iOS - inAppBrowser not working as expected

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I have my cordova application running version 3.9.2 (old i know), and my iPad is running 9.3.1. Recently since I have updated my iPad, the inAppBrowser links have stopped working as expected.

This is my code used for links (which worked fine until my iPad update)

```
function openURL(urlString) {
    myURL = encodeURI(urlString);
    window.open(myURL, '_blank');
}

<a href='#' onclick='openURL("http://www.google.com")'/>Google</a>
```

Previously, the link opened fine. Now something strange happens. When I click on the link, nothing happens..until I double click the home button (to show all open applications) then it works! How is this possible?! Nothing in my code has changed and it has baffled me.

Has anyone else came across this strange issue?

Cheers

**EDIT**

It seems if I remove the _blank on the window.open it works! But it doesn't allow me to go back to the application. So I have to restart the app to get back to where I was.

Comment: Whats the iOS version you updated to? Is it compatible with cordova version you are using?

Comment: I updated to iOS 9.3.1, and yes it is compatible

Comment: Any error trace on first click?

Comment: Nope nothing. As i said it has just started happening, no error..nothing. It's really confusing!

Comment: did you checked using safari web inspector?

Comment: Yes but nothing was showing up. I have updated my question, I use _blank on the window.open and that seems to be causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

For this plugin, at this moment the only supported target in OSX is `_system`.

So change your target `_blank` to it and you will be good.